# Flash with 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, flash, adobe

I understand this question has been asked so many time and believe me I have searched high and low for an answer to my problem.

But anyways, I am unable to get flash player to work. Doesn't matter what browser I use or what method.

I have tried just downloading it from the SC, I have tried unpacking it and just copying the to the plugin directory, I have tried flash-aid for firefox and I haven't found any other method.

The system I'm using is an old single core, 32 Bit AMD CPU and a Radeon 9200SE graphics card. I am just using it as a SMB server for my house. Even so, I would really like to sort the flash problem.

If anyone has any other ideas or another method I've missed, it would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using the .so file form flash 10.3 and copying it to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`